# What Eigenfunctions/distributions of the Fourier Transform exist?

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform, eigenfunctions

Apart from [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform), and the [Dirac comb distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) , what other Eigenfunctions or distributions of the Fourier transform exist?

Comment: There are a few questions already about eigenfunctions in the Schwartz space: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/how-do-i-compute-the-eigenfunctions-of-the-fourier-transform, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235413/eigenvalues-of-fourier-transform-on-schwartz-functions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728670/functions-that-are-their-own-fourier-transformation, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12045/what-are-fixed-points-of-the-fourier-transform

Comment: $\text{sech}(\pi x)$ is its own Fourier transform. The first thing to notice is that $T+\hat{T}+\hat{\hat{T}}+\hat{\hat{\hat{T}}}$ is always its own Fourier transform. Also as the Hermite functions are an orthonormal basis of $L^2$ which is dense in the distributions, any eigendistribution of the Fourier transform is a series of Hermite functions

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I will try to change my question so that it complements the already existing questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the domain of the Fourier Transform must be specifyed in this question.

The completeness of Hermite functions in $L_2$ implies that such space is divided $4$ orthogonal invariant (under the Fourier transform) spaces, which are orthogonal because the functions that composes them (The Hermite functions $\mod 4$ ) are so. Any function in such space is an eigenvector of the transform, and any funcion in the space can be expressed as linear combination of the functions, so **there are no more eigenvalues**. The complete reasoning can be found in

H. Dym y H.P. McKean — Fourier Series and Integrals, Academic Press (1972), pages 97-98.

Comment: Note that the Dirac comb is not in $L^2$.