# How to find eigenfunctions for the Fourier transform.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was searching for information on wikipedia, when I've came across a differential [equation to find eigenfunctions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#eigenfunctions) for the Fourier Transform:
$$
\left [U\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{d}{dx} \right) + U(x) \right ] \psi = 0
$$
Where $U(x)$, is a function which can be expressed as a Taylor series. But, my question is, how would you even arrive to this?
I've tried to start from the definition,
$$
\mathcal F [\psi] =\lambda \psi
$$
but I couldn't do much with it. So, how would I arrive to the differential equation, from this starting point?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "derive", since the word "derive" doesn't seem to be applicable to the approach taken here. It seems like what you're looking for is a motivation for this approach. In other words, the basic question is "how would you, as a mathematician who does not yet know the answer to the question, have thought of this approach?" Am I understanding the point of your question correctly?

Comment: The Wikipedia page does *not* suggest to start from $\mathcal{F}[\psi]=\lambda\psi.$ That is just what it means to be an eigenfunction. I'm not sure that the equation containing $U$ can be derived somehow; it might as well just have been created from knowledge about how the Fourier transform works.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, sorry, it is now edited. With "how to derive", I mean "how to arrive to".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Eigenfunctions/distributions of the Fourier Transform exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395369/what-eigenfunctions-distributions-of-the-fourier-transform-exist)